# Why does the Red Hulk stay as the Red Hulk?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers-vs-x-men, the-incredible-hulk

I get that [the Red Hulk has different powers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15218/3804) to the green variety of hulk, but until recently in AvX I thought that the Red Hulk was stuck in his red form, but then he transforms back

> into Thaddeus Ross to try and assassinate the Phoenix 5.

So I'm wondering, if he could transform at will, why stay as the Red Hulk all the time?

Comment: Is that a trick question? You are an insecure ex-general with feelings of inadequacy after years of chasing and getting beaten by the Hulk and then find yourself with the chance to have the same superhuman abilities as your arch-enemy AND get to stay yourself doing it. Why would you EVER change back into a human where you could fall down a flight of stairs and die? I'm just saying... Please don't be offended. I am just joking...

Comment: @Thaddeus but family, normal life? I don't know a great deal about old thunderbolt, so that'd be an answer. I thought he'd want to change back once in a while...

Comment: No, the man didn't have much of a family life and after he faked his death, it was basically over for him. He had disgraced himself after his decades of chasing the Hulk across the United States. His daughter Betty loved him but kept her distance if she could help it. In the end she got caught up with his issues. Being in love with Banner didn't help her cause either. General Ross was an obsessive wreck waiting to happen. No one is surprised at what happened to him.

Comment: So unlike Banner he gave into the monster inside years ago, so when it surfaces it's more him than his human side.

Comment: Ross was always obsessive. In his own way he was very much like the Hulk, destructive and problematic to anyone in his life. As the Red Hulk, he only increased the scale of the targets of his rage. Hopefully, they will eventually allow the character to gain some perspective and evolve as a character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: General Thunderbolt Ross had faked his death to throw off suspicion about being the Red Hulk, so legally he is dead.  Should he transform back into his human form he runs the risk of blowing that cover