# Who is the most powerful character Hulk has defeated ever?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I am asking it just out of curiosity. In The Marvel universe/multiverse who is the most powerful character whom The Incredible Hulk has defeated ever on his own (without someone's help)?

This question just popped in my head when I was reading [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15218/23268).

> "Both have shown the ability to fight metahuman opponents of vast power and have fought and defeated some of the most powerful beings in the Marvel Universe."

Comment: I'm not savvy on the history, but in the MCU he made short order out of Loki, a God. BUT! 

Depending on what level of reality you care to believe, [The Punisher killed damn near everyone in the Marvel Universe in a Garth Ennis comic](http://www.angelfire.com/alt/punisher/). And here is the 
[Splashpage:](http://www.angelfire.com/alt/punisher/images/00fc.jpg)

Comment: @MeatTrademark - Hah! That's nothing. [Deadpool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool#Deadpool_Kills_the_Marvel_Universe) not only killed the entire Marvel universe, he killed the Marvel writers and artists too (and perhaps the readers as well one day).

Comment: The Punisher is waaay cooler, in my opinion. He's just a regular human (no special healing powers or whatever) who breaks everything except the "[Fourth Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall)." Deadpool's too cheesy and chatty for me. Frank Castle (especially by Garth Ennis) is just too intense for that and has no time to talk to the readers or do anything but punish. [Punisher > Deadpool] Like Zaphod, he's just this guy, you know.

Comment: He won his fight against his wrath... that's a very hard adversary

Answer (score 7):

Sentry, Gladiator, Thor, the Abomination and Red Hulk, in that order! Before the arguments start, Gladiator has opened black hole with his hands and also destroyed planets with his hands so I would suggest he is more powerful than Thor.

I thought I would mention that Gladiator is vulnerable to certain forms of radiation. During this legendary battle Hulk realises this when he puts his hands on Gladiator's head, then tosses him into a reactor core.

[image: Hulk v Gladiator]

[image: Hulk v Gladiator]

Comment: He also fought the galaxy master in issue 111, arguably more powerful than any on your list.

Comment: Debatable, Richard. While the Galaxy Master was certainly more versatile in terms of his ability to project energy and change his shape, I am not certain he would be more powerful than Gladiator. He would certainly be equal to him in terms of raw energy output. You don't enslave entire galaxies by being a wimp...

Comment: I could have sworn I saw Hulk punching Galactus in some issue from the 80s or early 90s. Didn't knock him out or anything, but it was enough to stagger him back a few steps - definitely caught Galactus off-guard.